# Suspicious mongodb.log items

Tags: mongodb

My q_development.users table has more than 1,000,000 records. It is strange that my mongodb logs some long-time-consuming items on this collection without explicitly logging what the query is. MongoDB even do not log `ntoreturn` or `ntoskip` of those queries. It is very suspicious because the `reslen` are all the same. The logs look like the following

```
Fri May 25 00:01:00 [conn56429] query q_development.users nscanned:1207786 reslen:20 2390ms
Fri May 25 00:09:09 [conn55528] query q_development.users nscanned:1207799 reslen:20 2623ms
Fri May 25 00:11:11 [conn55529] query q_development.users nscanned:1207800 reslen:20 2660ms
Fri May 25 00:28:56 [conn55586] query q_development.users nscanned:1207823 reslen:20 2777ms
Fri May 25 00:46:45 [conn55529] query q_development.users nscanned:1207850 reslen:20 4218ms
Fri May 25 00:47:46 [conn56169] query q_development.users nscanned:1207851 reslen:20 2392ms
Fri May 25 01:30:49 [conn57141] query q_development.users nscanned:1207901 reslen:20 4289ms
```

Do you know what possible queries could generate such mongodb.log items? Thank you very much!

Comment: Looks like full scans. Who knows what you're doing there better than you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just means that some queries took a long time- the first one for example 2390ms. Anything that takes more than 100ms (by default) will get logged. In this case, it seems that queries for "users" take a lot of time. The `nscanned` shows how many documents had to be looked up from disk. It's over a million for each of them, which probably means that you're doing a full table scan-ie, a query without an index. Enable the [profiler](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+Profiler) to figure out which query is actually causing this unindexed full table scan.

In this case because no query is shown, it it likely that you do a find without arguments.

Comment: Thanks, but the thing is, I have set the profile option to maximum all, and it still does not log the actual query string of this very query. How to make the logger record the all queries?

Comment: Sounds like you might be simply doing a find without any criteria at all then on this collection. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: I changed `--verbose` to `--vv` (or more up to `--vvvvv`) and it showed the actual query. I'll edit the answer. Thanks anyway:)

Comment: What was the query? Can you edit your question so I can fix up the answer?